# define type of second parameter as generic class according to the first parameter of function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

considering the example below, the second parameter of `fn` function has the type `Base`, so is needed a class that contains an static attribute `controle` and an instance attribute `controle`, both of the type number.

```js
interface Base {
    controle: number
    new(...args: any[]): {
        controle: number
    }
}

function fn(constructor: Base) {
    return [constructor];
}

fn(class {
    static controle = 100;
    controle = 100;
});

fn(class {
    static controle = ""; // <--- throw type error
    controle = "";        // <--- throw type
});
```

[playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4oN4FgBQyRyCA9uFKQDYQBcyIArgLYBG0BxDEA7gBQA6IXCgBzDPTggAngG0AugEp6eQl2JkK1OgxbsonYgF8CJ-ARiMQCMMHLIYIPpoxgojG6Sj10WRclUuKAgwRigQZFkXNw8wL3kAblMCCycEKkwMAMMiVzhbBBJyN21kAF5kAEYABmqktSJNEppyqtr6o0V61OcMjCzA4jyCoq0WioAiCYTkAHpZ5AAeAFpV5DAAC0oedekABxRoSgMG0eaUSen1Ynml1eX1rdIdsH3DqGPTLqA)

---

considering the example below, the second parameter of `fn` function has the type `Base<T>` where `T` is a key of `DocumentEventMap`, ie if T is equal to "click", the second parameter of the `fn` function must be a class that contains an static attribute `type` and an instance attribute `type`, both of the type "click".

```js
type EventType = keyof DocumentEventMap;

interface Base <T extends EventType>{
    type: T
    new(...args: any[]): {
        type: T
    }
}

function fn(constructor: Base<"click">) {
    return [constructor];
}

fn(class {
    static type: "click" = "click";
    type: "click" = "click";
});

fn(class {
    static type: "abort" = "abort"; // <--- throw type error
    type: "abort" = "abort";        // <--- throw type error 
});
```

[playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAKuaBeKBrCID2AZlACL4DGArgLZLDx0CyAhmANwCwAUNwJbIQAToWbloAIWYBnaAB4UUCAA9gSACZTYCZGkgA+AN7coJqKEgAuKCmOnEEAO4AKAHRvmggOZSrzRCABtAF0ASisjLlMos3QrG0jTAF9uZJ4uQkpEcmBefEQoQkQncjypYEFKbPxBK0kZWQAicgAbXnJsBr0QqAiowQhgSkF8gJLEMoqqwSDOLlTuQuLm6U1e0zLmHPIYyygm1vaGqCx9to7ZqPMIK1PD472Ws4bZxJDZhaKWlZ7bEw2tnbXPbMABG1WARxOoPBzygAHo4VBZABaVFmAAWgnwDkBikEWMEv0BN2hggh9wapIhbGipgRSNRyIxWJxVzxBJSbyAA)

---

So here is my doubt, in the second example I hard coded `"click"` as generic type, but I want to turn it into a dynamic value, but I don't know how, please consider my attempt below:

```js
type EventType = keyof DocumentEventMap;

interface Base <T extends EventType>{
    type: T
    new(...args: any[]): {
        type: T
    }
}

function fn<K extends EventType>(type: K, constructor: Base<K>) {
    return [type, constructor];
}

fn("click", class {
    static type: "click" = "click";
    type: "click" = "click";
});

fn("click", class {
    static type: "abort" = "abort"; // <--- should throw type error, but it doesn't
    type: "abort" = "abort";        // <--- should throw type error, but it doesn't
});
```

[playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=22&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAKuaBeKBrCID2AZlACL4DGArgLZLDx0CyAhmANwCwAUNwJbIQAToWbloAIWYBnaAB4UUCAA9gSACZTYCZGkgA+AN7coJqKEgAuKCmOnEEAO4AKAHRvmggOZSrzRCABtAF0ASisjLlMos3QrG0jTAF9uZJ4uQkpEcmBefEQoQkRZAGlFFXVNBh10PSdzCCtigBoocjypYEFKbPxBK0kZEr0QqAiowQhgSkF8gPqWtsQOrp7BIM4uVO5CpwAicgAbXnJsXYWD6U0x0w7mHPIYyyh9o5PdqCwX49ONqPqrL5vD7PQ7fXYbRIhDbbRB7UFvc6XUa2Ey3e6PBrPZgAI16wHenxxePBUAA9KSoLIALQ0qBSAAW+EoBzUZnpgnwDgxikEHMELWxlGAUF4wrU+AgUkQAHJgCiMQCiYJ8cDdkr8WxoqZyZSaVS6YzmazgOzOdyhHyBUKRWKJVLZSkoUA)

So here is my question, how to properly get the second parameter as a generic class accord to the first parameter of a function.

---

*I'm a Brazilian, my English is not so good, so I ask to anyone who can correct my text to fell free to do that.*

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this situation, see the solution below:

```js
type EventType = keyof DocumentEventMap;

interface Base<T extends EventType> {
    type: T
    new(...args: any[]): {
        type: T
    }
}

function fn<K extends EventType, U extends Base<K>>(type: K, constructor: U) {
    return [type, constructor];
}

fn("click", class {
    static type: "click" = "click";
    type: "click" = "click";
});

fn("click", class {
    static type: "abort" = "abort"; // <--- throw type error
    type: "abort" = "abort";        // <--- throw type error
});
```

[payground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogbhAdsAKuaBeKBrCID2AZlACL4DGArgLZLDx0CyAhmANwCwAUNwJbIQAToWbloAIWYBnCAB4UUCAA9gSACZTYCZGkgA+KAG9uUU1FCQAXFBQmziCAHcAFADp3zQQHMp15ohAAbQBdAEprYy4zaPN0a1soswBfbhSeLkJKRHJgXnxEKEJEWQBpRRV1TQYddAAaKABVctVEDShJGVK9PWcLCGsS+vJ8qWBBShz8QWsG0KM7U0EIYEpBAsC+oZGxieAp4M4uNO4i5wAicgAbXnJsM6HL6U1I6NHmXPJYqygL69uzqBYX43O6HaJ9azA-6An5XEFnQ5JUKHE6Ic5w-4PJ7zRKmN4fL79H7MABGU2AAKBpPJCKgAHo6VBZABaVnmAAWgnwjkJikEXMEC0JkOpggpMLOoopbBiZgZTNZzI5XJ5fT5AtSyKAA)

---

To solve the problem I created a second generic type it depends of the first generic type `K extends EventType, U extends Base<K>`.